# Java gui box creater

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Hi there trying to make a game and sturgging as its the first time iam playing around with the gui in java. All i am trying to figure out is how do i make a box with a black border which is this size foe example :

```
------------------
|                |      
|                |
|                |      
|                |  
|                |
------------------
```

Then when the user clicks on it it will change the black border to a red border and then the user can write a number in it from 1-5. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Information is quite rare, but I think, this will lead you to the first steps:

I guess, as you tagged jframe you want to use Swing and a JFrame.

Try this:

```
LineBorder border = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK);
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(border)
```

Add it to your contentpane of jfame.

Learn to write a Mouse Listener (easiest is to override a MouseAdapter) and add it to the Panel (addMouseListener). One Method of the listener (guess which :) ) should change the bordercolor of the panel.

Have fun.

Comment: Thank you i will try this. Its just hard getting the user input into that box but iam sure i will get it at the end :)

Comment: A keylistener will do that for you... The panel can hold a label that the keylistener should write to... good luck.

Comment: If you try this, please click "Accepted" to my answer as it gives me reputation points :D

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really that much information here to give you a good answer. However, I'm assuming you are interested in Swing given by the tag JFrame. I'd suggest you take a look at the Swing tutorial on oracle's website [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: What do u mean? i just said i really want a 5 by 5 box which a user can enter a number into to. Thats all :)

Comment: What fiveofakind means is that you have tagged this question with the "JFrame" keyword.  JFrame is a particular type of container in Java's Swing tools.  He's made the assumption (as I did) that you want to use a JFrame for your game based on that tag.  The link he provided is to the official tutorial on using Swing components, its really quite good and easy to follow.  I'd advise you to have a read through and look at the examples, everything you need is in there.